# Using django Auth app in my own project

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to customize auth app of django to use it in my project. I just create the project, the app, models and the `admin.py`. my question is: where should I customize the users by coding not from the `admin` page? should I include the user into the `models` or create my own `user.py` file??

sorry for trivial question, I'M Newbie to django and I'm still confused about it.

Comment: Why are you customising auth? And what do you mean by customising the users? Did you want to add fields or something to the model?

Comment: I need to add extra fields to the users , this is what I meant with customization. I also want the users to control some of the models like their own posts.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on [customizing the auth app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/)?

Comment: Be wary, you should not give regular users access to the admin. Doing "row level permissions" in the admin isn't built in. You grant access to models and all the data in those models via the admin.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton for that reason I wanted the user to have his own page and can modify his posts, however I don't know where to include the extra fields of the user rather than the admin page

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes I did, but I don't know where should I include its code, like this piece of code : [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Answer (score 1):

To customise the User, you should read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). But you should note the caveat:

> Model design considerations
>   Think carefully before handling information not directly related to authentication in your custom User Model.
>
> It may be better to store app-specific user information in a model that has a relation with the User model. That allows each app to specify its own user data requirements without risking conflicts with other apps. On the other hand, queries to retrieve this related information will involve a database join, which may have an effect on performance.

Model code should always go in your applications `models.py` file. You tell django which model to use with the setting:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

Which would use the model `MyUser` in the file:

```
/yourproject/yourapp/models.py
```